# sql server 2008, altering the table layout

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please find the blow table.

**TABLE**

```
ClientID    Balance1    Balance2    Balance3    Balance4    Balance5    Balance6    Balance7    Balance8    Balance9
A           NULL        NULL        NULL        3           Null        Null        Null        Null        Null
B           10          null        Null        Null        20          Null        Null        Null        NULL
C           Null        8           Null        10          Null        Null        1           Null        NULL
D           Null        19          Null        Null        Null        Null        Null        Null        NULL
E           Null        Null        50          Null        Null        Null        Null        Null        NULL
F           NULL        NULL        NULL        30          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
G           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        80          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

How can I modify the above table into as shown below by using query, Please help!

```
ClientID    Balance1    Balance2    Balance3    Balance4    Balance5    Balance6    Balance7    Balance8    Balance9
A           NULL        NULL        NULL        3           3           3           3           3           3   
B           10          10          10          10          20          20          20          20          20
C           Null        8           8           10          10          10          1           1           1
D           Null        19          19          19          19          19          19          19          19
E           Null        Null        50          50          50          50          50          50          50          
F           NULL        NULL        NULL        30          30          30          30          30          30          
G           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        80          80          80          80          80
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to do an update, or how to set all null columns in a row with the preceeding populated column's value?

Comment: @JohnLBevan, I didn't get sentese to explaing the situation. I'm asking for "how to set all null columns in a row with the preceeding populated column's value?"

Comment: Cool, thanks @OverflowUser - thought I'd check before answering to avoid giving a really confusing answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
update myTable
set balance9 = coalesce(balance9 ,balance8 ,balance7 ,balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance8 = coalesce(balance8 ,balance7 ,balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance7 = coalesce(balance7 ,balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance6 = coalesce(balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance5 = coalesce(balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance4 = coalesce(balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance3 = coalesce(balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance2 = coalesce(balance2 ,balance1)
```

Working Example:

```
declare @myTable table 
(
    clientId nchar(1) not null primary key clustered
    , balance1 int null
    , balance2 int null
    , balance3 int null
    , balance4 int null
    , balance5 int null
    , balance6 int null
    , balance7 int null
    , balance8 int null
    , balance9 int null
)

insert into @myTable (clientId, balance3, balance6)
values ('X',8,12)

update @myTable
set balance9 = coalesce(balance9 ,balance8 ,balance7 ,balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance8 = coalesce(balance8 ,balance7 ,balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance7 = coalesce(balance7 ,balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance6 = coalesce(balance6 ,balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance5 = coalesce(balance5 ,balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance4 = coalesce(balance4 ,balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance3 = coalesce(balance3 ,balance2 ,balance1)
,   balance2 = coalesce(balance2 ,balance1)

select * from @myTable
```

Comment: I think we are nearly there, If our query works for ClientID 'C', scenario. If you could observ there multiple column values in a same row. Thank You!

Comment: +1 - That should work, and it's *far* cleaner than my answer is.  Great use of `coalesce`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to update each column individually, and sequentially, like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Balance2 = Balance1 
WHERE Balance2 IS NULL AND Balance1 IS NOT NULL

UPDATE YourTable
SET Balance3 = Balance2
WHERE Balance3 IS NULL AND Balance2 IS NOT NULL
```

To make sure that either all of your updates occur, or none of your updates occur, you may want to wrap all of your statements in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement.

You need a few statements like the following:

```
UPDATE
    [YourTableName]
SET
    [Balance5] = '3',
    [Balance6] = '3',
    [Balance7] = '3',
    [Balance8] = '3',
    [Balance9] = '3'
WHERE
    [ClientID] = 'A'
```

Make sure you have an appropriate `WHERE` clause, otherwise you might be updating more data than you intended. It can be a good practice to wrap the update queries in a `TRAN` that you initially rollback, to make sure you are getting an expected rowcount.